# Using a Object property as method argument

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a rather complex database, where we are using Linq to SQL. I'm creating a model layer where I would like to only have one method. But my problem is that we often like to order the collection. Is it possible somehow to accomplish something like this:

```
public static List<Object> GetObject(Object.Property)
{
   return some Linq.ToList();
}
```

I know I can use linq on my list afterwards.

Hmm it was maybe a bit to diffuse question.

OK I solved it with reflection and a string in the argument..

```
MyObjectDataDataContext context = new MyObjectDataDataContext ();

PropertyInfo[] piArray = context.MyObject.GetType().GetProperties();
PropertyInfo pi = piArray.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == "property");
if (pi != null)
{
    return context.MyObject.OrderBy(t => pi.PropertyType);
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to do with object.property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to access the same data, but depending on a 'column' criteria, return the data sorted?

Once you have the IEnumerable data, you can sort it as follows:

```
list.OrderBy(t => t.ColumnYouWantToSortBy)
```

As in the following [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

Comment: Partly yes partly no - My question was probably to diffuse